# Error when trying to run RandomForestClassifer with Pipieline and GridSearch

Tags: python, random-forest, grid-search, pipelines

I am trying to run a **RandomForest Classifier** using **Pipeline**, **GridSerach** and **CV**

I am getting an error when I fit the data. I am not sure how to fix it.

Will appreciate any help on this.

My code is:

```
 column_trans = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(), ['CategoricalData']),
 remainder='passthrough')
 RF = RandomForestClassifier()
 pipe = make_pipeline(column_trans, RF)

 # Set grid search params
 grid_params = [{'RF__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
 'RF__min_samples_leaf': [5,10,20,30,50,80,100],
 'RF__max_depth': [3,4,6,8,10],
 'RF_min_samples_split': [2,4,6,8,10]}]

 # Construct grid search
 gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe,
 param_grid = grid_params,
 scoring='accuracy',
 cv=5)

 gs.fit(train_features, train_target)  ----This is where I get an error


 ValueError: Invalid parameter RF for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('columntransformer',
             ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                               transformers=[('onehotencoder',
                                              OneHotEncoder(),
                                              ['CategoricalData'])])),
            ('randomforestclassifier', RandomForestClassifier())]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Comment: You are missing an underscore in `RF_min_samples_split`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding a '_' I had to replace RF by randomforestclassifier in all grid params - Please see link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62166539/9592484

Answer (score 0):

Use randomforestclassifier__ instead of RF__

`````
column_trans = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(), ['categorical_column'],
                                       remainder='passthrough')
RF = RandomForestClassifier()
pipe = make_pipeline(column_trans, RF)
# Set grid search params
grid_params = [{'randomforestclassifier__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
                'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_leaf': [5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 80, 100],
                'randomforestclassifier__max_depth': [3, 4, 6, 8, 10],
                'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_split': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]}]

# Construct grid search
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe,
                  param_grid=grid_params,
                  scoring='accuracy',
                  cv=5)

gs.fit(train_features, train_target)
````
`````